# Is there a way to use `zerolog` logger in cadence workflows instead of `zap` logger?

Tags: logging, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I know that Cadence uses it's own internal non-exported `context`. That kind of makes it hard to get the values from it, as there is no conversion between `workflow.Context` and `context.Context`. But maybe there is another way I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in Cadence. In Temporal you can inject any dependencies using [interceptors](https://github.com/temporalio/go-sdk/blob/d843b784901c70fbcd4404aecda5f953725e0f19/interceptors/workflow_interceptor.go#L33). Also Temporal switched the logger to an [interface](https://github.com/temporalio/go-sdk/blob/ad87da1b54d782ad2a22efd0e95d4922920799a0/log/logger.go#L29), so you can use the exposed interface and write an adapter to the zerolog logger.

Comment: I ended up with the solution of adapter extracting the desired values from workflow.Context and adding them as `zerolog` fields

Answer (score 0):

In Cadence you can use whatever logger you like in Activity including zerolog. For example we used our own fancy logger in Cadence system worker:
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/11547ee6db5dd306cb507b263381a6ea94c3faf1/service/worker/scanner/history/scavenger.go#L34
https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/11547ee6db5dd306cb507b263381a6ea94c3faf1/service/worker/scanner/history/scavenger.go#L286

It has strongly typed tags so that people can't make mistakes in putting tags.

But things are different in workflow. You definitely can't simply directly use you own logger in workflows. Because workflow can be replayed at any time. Cadence must ensure that logging is skiped during replying. Otherwise you may see weird logs.

So what end up happening if you want to use some other logger? The current answer is that you have to implement an interface. In Cadence you need to implement the `zap.Core` interface, and passing it when creating worker. In other words you can implement it using `zerolog`. But you can't directly using it in workflow code. You must use "workflow.GetLogger()".